# как импортировать библиотеку jar?

Tags: java, библиотеки, импорт

Возможно ли без помощи каких-либо IDE и без настроек переменных сред импортировать библиотеку командами java в текущий проект, зная что она точно находиться скажем в "C:/library.jar"?

Comment: Возможно вам пригодится пункт "Используем пакеты" из этого поста: https://habrahabr.ru/post/125210/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. при компиляции добавить в classpath путь до jar архива
2. если вы используете программу сборки, вроде maven то можно импортировать архив в локальный репозиторий, например, [так](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)